# How to use Internet on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ubuntu-14.04, dell-inspiron, wifi-configuration

On my Dell laptop, I installed VMwarePlayer first and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is fine except the Internet is not accessible on Ubuntu (but still okay on Win 7)

The configurations are:

- Dell laptop, Inspiron-15-5547 Win7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1, 64 bit
- VMware® Player: 6.0.3 build-1895310
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Wifi: university wifi (eduroam)

I also tried "Bridged", "NAT" and "Host-only" for the "Network connection". All seem not work. 
[image]

If I should use "Bridged", what is the settings I should use? I tried check and uncheck "Replicate physical network connection state" but both not work.

Can I ask how to enable the internet in Ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: You need to Bridge your actual Ethernet port to VmWare port.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with player, but you need to set the VM's NIC to Bridged mode. This will cause it to pull an IP from your LAN DHCP server and participate in your LAN like any other (non-virtual) computer.

Comment: I have tried, but not work  @duDE

Comment: Set it to bridged, and then start troubleshooting whatever trouble remains. Bridged is the correct setting in this case, but you have at least one other issue.